# Using Codeigniters template parsers generated values in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, date-format

I fetch the content from a db, I get a `result_array()`. Then I parse the view and place the tags accordingly in my HTML. However one of the fields is a datetime type field and I wish to format that a little. Usually I would just run a `date_format` on the value and be done with it, but with the parsed output that doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example:

```
{array_start}
  {title}
  <?=date_format({datetime_value}, 'Y-m-d')?>
  {body}
{/array_end}
```

Throws a fatal error saying "Failed to parse string ({datetime_value})" when I put single quotes around it and when I remove any quotes it gives me a syntax error as the dt value becomes a constant in that context.

How can I handle this better? The parsed `{datetime_value}` works just fine on it's own, I just can't figure out how to format it in that state.

Comment: Is it not possible to format it and put it in another variable, then use that in your template?

Answer (score 1):

Just use regular PHP, just because you're using a templating system doesn't mean you can't. My guess is it's just populating a variable and the template is echoing that variable in the curly braces.

This should work:

```
<?=date_format($datetime_value, 'Y-m-d')?>
```